# Sum of two closed sets in $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets of $X=[0,\infty)$. Is $A+B$ closed in $X$ ?

I know $A+B$ need not be closed in $X=\Bbb{R}$ as $A=\Bbb{Z}$ and $B=\pi \Bbb{Z}$ serve an example

What about this one? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n\in A$ and $b_n\in B$. Assume that $a_n+b_n$ converges to $c$. Here observe that $\langle a_n\rangle$ is bounded. Can you find the reason why?

> This is because $0\le a_n\le a_n+b_n$ and $\langle a_n+b_n\rangle$ is bounded.

Now take a subsequence $\langle a_{n_k}\rangle$ of $\langle a_n\rangle$ which has a limit $a\in A$. Then $\langle b_{n_k}\rangle$ also converges to some $b\in B$.  Therefore $c=a+b$ so $c\in A+B$.

Comment: The fact  "any bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence" imply that the limit point $c$ of $A+B$ must a member of $A+B$ and so $A+B$ is closed. Thanks! Am I right?

Comment: @LearningMathematics Yes, though there are many gaps in your comment.

Comment: What are they? Can you explain a bit more? Why this sequential method does't work for $A=\Bbb{Z}$ and $B=\pi \Bbb{Z}$ ? Is it the terms of the sequence must be positive?

Comment: @LearningMathematics I just means you need more steps to get a proof; To compare with your counterexample, they can have a limit of the form $\infty-\infty$. It can't happen if $A,B\subseteq [0,\infty)$.

Comment: @LearningMathematics To elaborate my previous comment, sum of two sequence can be bounded unless each sequence is not bounded if we does not assume $A,B\subseteq [0,\infty)$.